# module exports passing argument to a arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

trying to import this function into another page so i can pass it the user paramerters when i do it like this

```
const { post } = require("./utilities/apiCalls")


 console.log( post);
```

This wont throw an error but it will give me undefined how can i pass an object with info to this function is what im asking more or less

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');


const post = async(user) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/${user.name}').then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => console.log(json))
        return response
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
module.exports = post
```

Comment: Notice that `response` will always be the return value of `console.log(…)`, which is `undefined`. Don't use `then`, use only `await`!

Answer (score 2):

You should rather import it as `const post = require("./utilities/apiCalls")` or export as `module.exports = {post}`